# Does jmh tests only run on Hotspot?

Tags: java, jvm, jmh

How can I set jmh parameters so I can run tests on different virtual machine?

I have tried to change -jvm //path to the virtual machine.

I get this error:

```
Error parsing command line:
 'X' is not a recognized option
<forked VM failed with exit code 1>
<stdout last='20 lines'>
</stdout>
<stderr last='20 lines'>
Error parsing command line:
'X' is not a recognized option
</stderr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JMH relies on non-standard JVM settings to gain the explicit control over VM (see the exact command line with `-v EXTRA`). Notably, `-XX:CompileCommand` is used to force compiler to inline/don't-inline the specific methods. These non-standard options are available in HotSpot-based JDKs only.

While you may hack JMH to work with non-HotSpot VMs, nobody will test the critical parts of the benchmark infrastructure perform reliably. In other words, you are entering the gray area where you have to seek the non-HotSpot VM vendor's assistance in benchmarking (and maybe retrofitting JMH, if license allows, for their VM).